# enumerate with six library in python dictionary

Tags: python, six, iteritems

I can use enumerate with python dictionary like so:

```
for count, (key, value) in enumerate(my_dict.iteritems(), 1):
    print key, value, count
```

How do I use enumerate with the iteritems function from the six library?

Comment: `dict`s are unordered (generally), you could obtain an index via `enumerate`, but it won't be consistent

Comment: ah yes, I am using python 3.6 though. I think dicts are ordered there

Comment: they are but don't rely on that! use a `collections.OrderedDict`

Comment: thanks @Chris_Rands, this is very helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `six.iteritems` equivalent of `my_dict.iteritems()` is `six.iteritems(my_dict)`, so:

```
for count, (key, value) in enumerate(six.iteritems(my_dict), 1):
    print key, value, count
```